# Swift Package Manager CLI not building properly for multiple platforms

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, swift-package-manager

I've installed Swift from Swift.org for windows and macOS, configured path variables, reinstalled, and repeated the process all over. Every single time, I run into an issue when trying to build a swift library or executable, where the compiler says my manifest (Package.swift) file is incorrect (even though sometimes it hasn't changed from the default one it gives me) and it says I'm missing an assortment of different packages such as SwiftShims or PackageDescription (which should be built in).

Every time I use ChatGPT to solve this problem, it just tells me to reinstall swift or add swift to my path. Neither fix the issue.

The error:

```
error: 'igis': Invalid manifest
Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx11.0
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file "/Users/ryan/Desktop/Coding Projects/LocalIgis/Igis/Package.swift" -target arm64-apple-macosx11.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI -swift-version 5 -package-description-version 5.0.0 -disable-implicit-concurrency-module-import -disable-implicit-string-processing-module-import -target-sdk-version 13.1 -module-name main -o /var/folders/2r/lz06dbtj5cld3fm5hd_t6_d80000gn/T/Package-de527f.o
/Users/ryan/Desktop/Coding Projects/LocalIgis/Igis/Package.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'PackageDescription'
import PackageDescription
```

The Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Igis",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
          name: "Igis",
          type: .dynamic,
          targets: ["Igis"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git", from: "2.42.1")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "Igis",
            dependencies: ["NIO",
                           "NIOHTTP1",
                           "NIOWebSocket"]),
        .testTarget(
          name: "IgisTests",
          dependencies: ["Igis"]),
    ]
)
```